# Enable Password Char in TextBox except last N character / Limit Masked Char

Tags: c#, textbox

How to enable Password Char in TextBox except last N character?

I already tried this method

```
cardnumber.Select((c, i) => i < cardnumber.Length - 4 ? 'X' : c).ToArray()
```

But it is so hard to manipulate, I will pass original card value in every event like `Keypress`,
`TextChange` and etc..

Is there I way that is more simple and easy to managed?

Comment: you mean, everytime the user inputs a char, the last input is shown?

Comment: atleast after the user inputs, like the last 4 or 5 char will be shown the rest is not

Comment: hm? You've got a TextBox and you want to display all chars as "*" except the last ones?

Comment: @Yami Yes, atleast last 4 i need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```
string pw = "password1234";
char[] splitpw;
string cenpw;
int NtoShow;

splitpw = new char[pw.Length];
splitpw = pw.ToCharArray();
NtoShow = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < pw.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < pw.Length - NtoShow)
        cenpw += "*";
    else
        cenpw += splitpw[i];
}

//cenpw: "********1234"
```